# Graduate with short term employments: Should I leave this job off my CV?

Tags: resume, job-change, quitting, career-switch, employment-gaps

I've recently graduated, but as I was studying I did a part time weekend job which I did for 3 years. As soon as my studies finished, I got offered a full time job, which I thought would be a good idea to move onto.

Comment: Or ["Should I leave two short term jobs off of my resume?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70056/should-i-leave-two-short-term-jobs-off-of-my-resume) or ["Should short term jobs on LinkedIn profile be left off?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14260/should-short-term-jobs-on-linkedin-profile-be-left-off)

Answer (score 1):

Like all things, the answer depends.  Some of the factors are "what industry are you working in," and "whether those jobs were relevant to your studies."  Since you are a recent graduate, I would assume that your work experience is limited.  That would lead me to list as the following:

- Company C, Your Role/Title, October 2016 - Present

  - [ what are you doing here]
- Company B, Your Role/Title, August 2016 - October 2016

  - [ what you did there ]
- Company A, Your Role/Title, September 2013 - September 2016

  - [ what you did there ]

There's no need to mention that the work at Company A is part-time.  That should be obvious when looking at the overlap with your studies.  As for Company B, if it was contract work, then I would mention that.  If you left because of a bad fit between yourself and the company, then you'll need to explain that when someone asks.  Otherwise, since the time period is so short, you could leave it off and say that the two months of unemployment were you trying to find the right position with a number of small contracts that were of little consequence.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The 6 week job was not a contract position and it was not connected to my studies but neither were any of the other jobs and my new one.  If I leave it off, would it be explainable to say I left the weekend job for more opportunities ? Though it may be strange if an offer wasnt in place at that time.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily think it is strange to have left a job to focus full-time on a job hunt.  If you were to leave off the second job, the time between the 1st and 3rd isn't so great as to arouse suspicion that you were idle or anything else bad.  Since we are talking about early career, deciding to stop working (if able) to focus on a job search shows that you are really taking into consideration your next moves.  That there is a desire to find the right long-term job so that there will be a mutually beneficial fit between yourself and the company you do join.